# web scraping with python and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to extract data from a web site and the data are in a table :

```
url=requests.get("xxxxx")
soup =BeautifulSoup(url.content)
table=soup.find_all("table")[0]
rows = table.find_all('tr')
```

I tried this code it works but only 42 lines are extracted and the source table contains 220 lines ?
someone tell me how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome.
2 possibilities. Javascript or website security.

`requests` is javscript agnostic and doesn't execute any javascript code. You'll want a headless browser solution (`selenium` is popular) that more closely mimicks a browser, especially when it comes to javascript.

Many websites don't want to be scraped and employ different methods to prevent it. The simplest form is checking the `User-Agent` value of the client (your `Python` script) or rate-throttling (20k refreshes a second isn't human). e.g., if the `User-Agent` is anything other than a [known value](http://useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?name=Firefox), it'll behave differently (little or no data). Other forms of defense are more complex. Such as trying to play audio on your "browser" or polling your "browser"'s resolution. For that you'll need to investigate the site's behavior. This can take time. You can start off with either the `Networking` tab of your browser's developing tools (F12 on Firefox) or [Zap Proxy](https://www.zaproxy.org) for more refined control.

Comment: I used webdriver from selenium but it returns the same the result. And the second possibility I didn't understant well what I have to do ?

Comment: @kloud You want to investigate how the site behaves during normal usage and compare it to its behavior when accessed with a script. This means, polling what types of requests your browser makes vs the script. What types of responses the browser gets vs your script. So on and so forth until you manage to find that particular site's defenses. How does it manage to detect your script? There's no "one stop shop" solution for this. It can be different each time.